# Question about mean sojourn time on non compact space

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, entropy

I'm reading a paper by Micheal Handel, Bruce Kitchens and Daniel J. Rudolph on Entropy  http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02761650 I have some problem

I couldnt show that $\mu(\bigcup_{N\ge1}G_N(C))=1 $ in following lemma

**Lemma:**

If $(X,d)$ be non compact metric space and $\mu$ be Borel probability measure on $X$ and invariant under $T:X\to X$ and compact set $C$ with $\mu(C) > 1-\delta/2$

There is a compact set $K \subseteq C$ with $\mu(K) > 1 - \delta$ and an $N$ so that for every
$n\ge N$ and $x \in K$
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{1}_{C}(T^{i}x)\ge 1-\delta$$
where $\mathbb{1}_{C}$ is characteristic function.

to prove this lemma author is used following process.

For each $N\ge1$ we define

$$G_N(C)=\{x \in X :\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{1}_{C}(T^{i}x)\ge 1-\delta,
\forall n\ge N \}$$

and take $K=C\cap G_N(C)$

**1.**  $G_N(C)$ is closed so $K$ is compact

but I couldn't show that $\mu(K) > 1 - \delta$

Comment: If $\mu$ is ergodic then $\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty G_N(C)=X$ up to measure zero using the Birkhoff ergodic theorem, but if $\mu$ is not ergodic (and especially, if $\mu$ has infinitely many ergodic components) then the result is less clear. The original text of the paper seems not to consider the non-ergodic case. Is it used in the arguments which follow the lemma?

Comment: @Ian Morris yes when $\mu$ is ergodic its clear but the question is why its true for invariant and probability measure. and in this lemma $\mu$ is non-ergodic

Comment: You should mention the exact authors, I edited to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Edited]** after comment by the asker and corrected a computation.

I think you can use the [ergodic theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory#Ergodic_theorems) for merely invariant measures,  *but the lemma might need some adaptation* (without access to the article, I cannot tell whether such adaptation hurts or not -- you should link to openly accessible version of the article whenever available).

---

**[Further edit]** Indeed here is a *counter-example to the original lemma.* Let $T:\mathbb{S}^1\times [0,1]\to \mathbb{S}^1\times [0,1]$ be defined by $T(x,y)=(x+\theta,y)$ where $\theta$ is an irrational number, and let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure. For any small $\delta$, let $C$ be the union of $[0,1-\frac{11}{10}\delta]\times [0,1/2]$ and $\mathbb{S}^1\times [1/2,1]$; $C$ has measure $1/2-\frac{11}{20}\delta+1/2>1-\delta/2$. On the other hand, the set $G_N(C)$ consist of only  $\mathbb{S}^1\times [1/2,1]$ so that you cannot get $K$ with measure more than $1/2$, however small was $\delta$ in the first place.

---

Here is a proof of a weakened Lemma, which might be sufficient to get the main conclusion from the article.

Let us assume that $\mu(C)>1-\alpha\delta$, and then tailor the $\alpha$ to get the desired conclusion.

The time averages converge in $L^1$ to some invariant measurable function $g$, which might not be constant since $\mu$ is not assumed to be ergodic, but which is positive and less than 1 by construction and has the same integral than the original function by the ergodic theorem. This means it has integral at least $1-\alpha\delta$, and since it cannot exceed one it must be close to $1$ on a large set. More precisely, 
$$1-\alpha\delta<\int g d\mu \le \mu(\{g\ge1-\delta\})+(1-\delta)(1-\mu(\{g\ge1-\delta\})) \\=1-\delta+\delta \mu(\{g\ge1-\delta\})$$
so that $\mu(\{g\ge1-\delta\})> 1-\alpha$ (my originial computation had a sign error, I assumed the signed that was convenient was the correct one - have to learn from that).

Note that you don't get $\mu(\cup G_N(C))=1$, and actually **[edited]** you *cannot* expect it: if $T:\{0,1\}\to\{0,1\}$ is the identity map and $C=\{0\}$ then $G_N(C)=C$ for all $N$.

Now for $N$ large enough the finite time-average must be larger than $1-\delta$ on a set of size $1-\alpha$, i.e. $\mu(G_N(C))> 1-\alpha$ (apply the above displayed computation to $x\mapsto \frac1N\sum_{0}^{N-1} \mathbb{1}_C(T^ix)$ instead of $g$, with $N$ large enough that the integral is bounded below by $1-\alpha\delta$). Taking $K=C\cap G_N(C)$ you get $\mu(K)\ge 1- \alpha\delta-\alpha$. To have $\mu(K)\ge 1-\delta$, we take $\alpha=\delta/(1+\delta)$ i.e. assume $\mu(C)>1-\delta^2/(1+\delta)$, which is *stronger* than the original assumption.

Comment: I didn't understand your solution if we take 
 $\phi(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{1}_{C}(T^{i}x)\ge 1-\delta$
then we have 
$$1-\delta\le\mu(C)=\int_X\phi(x)d\mu(x)\le1$$  but How did you proceed to show that $\mu(\bigcup_{N\ge1}G_N(C))=1 $

Comment: @maisamhedyelloo  I don't think this equality will hold, and my proposal only gives a weaker lemma of the same kind. I will try to determine if one can do better but don't have time right now.

Comment: Thanks  Dear Benoît. just let Quick look at my answer and I think my answer in on the verge of Proof. Could you complete it.

Comment: @maisamhedyelloo: I will not dive into your proof, which cannot be fixed: $\mu(\cup G_N(C))$ **can** be less than $1$. It might still be possible to obtain the lemma as it is written, I don't know.

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand this part of your proof Now for $N$ large enough the finite time-average must be larger than $1-\delta$ on a set of size $1-\alpha$, i.e. $\mu(G_N(C))> 1-\alpha$.

Comment: @maisamhedyelloo: you should be more specific. Is the problem the term "finite time-average"? Is it the correspondence between the two parts of the proof? Is it the first statement?

Comment: I understand $\exists N\in \mathbb N\quad\forall n\ge N:\quad\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{1}_{C}(T^{i}x)\ge 1-\delta$

but I dont understand How did you get $\mu(\{x\in X : \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{1}_{C}(T^{i}x)\ge 1-\delta , \forall n \ge N\})1-\alpha$

Comment: @maisamhedyelloo: Iprecised that point, but after that you are on your own.